# View a JIRA issue as readonly

Tags: jira

When a JIRA issue is assigned to me, I keep the issue page open so I can read fields, description, attachments, etc. But the problem is, any place I click, the fields enters in edit mode. I fear change anything by accident, so I was thinking if there is some way to put the ticket in "readonly mode", so I can change something only if I click some "edit" button, or visit a specific url. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to configure this at a user-level, but there is a project level setting to adjust on the applications settings page (if you have admin-level permissions for it). `https://_your_url_.atlassian.net/secure/admin/EditApplicationProperties!default.jspa`

Someone had requested this as a feature 7 years ago, but it seems like the JIRA development team has not actioned it. (as seen: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-29091)